# org.hibernate.Query cannot be converted to org.hibernate.query.Query [javac] Query query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery);

Tags: java, hibernate, ant

i'm updating my project from hibernate 4.3.5 to 5.2.10. i updated the jars but getting below error during ant build.

> error: incompatible types: org.hibernate.Query cannot be converted to org.hibernate.query.Query
>       [javac]             Query query =   session.createQuery(sqlQuery);

i can't understand why? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classpath should contain only single version of hibernate jars, version 5 in this case. Please remove any other version of jars if present.

Answer (score 0):

The  `Query` object type of `query` is `org.hibernate.query.Query`. But the return value of method `session.createQuery(sqlQuery)` is `org.hibernate.Query`, not same type of `query` variable.

Comment: I have not changed any code into Dao class. My code has imported org.hibernate.Query which i can see. should i import from org.hibernate.query.Query and does it  need any code changes .? I have done only library related and build path related changes. @Anh Duong

Comment: If you updating your project from hibernate 4.3.5 to 5.2.10, you need update only object type in code when create query.